# Schedule a task to be executed without requiring user login

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

This is a very specific scenario because the script is executed on a rescue machine that has the main disk of the target machine attached.

The rescue machine will perform some operations on the disk but the final one requires some script to be executed in the target machine.

I'm currently loading the registry on the attached volume with:

```
reg load HKLM\TARGETINSTANCE_SOFTWARE "$($gDrive)Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE"
```

and setting my task to execute on:

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\TARGETINSTANCE_SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
```

That works, but with one big caveat: It's only executed once a user logs in, but I need this task to be executed upon the system boot even without user logged.

Is it possible to set it like this, having just the disk drive attached as a secondary device?

Comment: Are you actually booting the system from the target system disk? If not, then it's going to behave like a removable drive ... Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, could you provide more detail?

Comment: No, the "rescue" machine boots on its own system disk, and the target disk behaves like a removable drive indeed. That's why I set the registry by loading a file. Instead of reaching the current machine's registry, I'm reaching the one stored in the target system disk

Comment: The goal is to have the registry in the target instance so it can execute the command I want once it boots, and it works, once I log in the script I set runs right away. But I need it to execute even without any user logged in. So perhaps it would be just another registry path